# Remove the 11. value of string if exists

Tags: regex, string, autoit

I have the string of the following format:

example 1: ABC,0,ABCD,ABC,ABC,ABC,ABC,ABC,11,ABC,ABC,toRemove,012,234

example 2: ABC,0,ABCD,ABC,ABC,ABC,ABC,ABC,11,ABC,ABC, toRemove,012,234

If the string contains 14 Values (instead of 13 values) separated by comma, then remove the 12. value

The second line above contains a white space, that should also removed if exists.

Comment: Does AutoIt have a function for splitting a string on a delimiter? That seems like the better way to do this than a regular expression.

Comment: Yes it's possible: autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm I think this a good idea :)  Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved:

$line = StringSplit($tmp_line, ",")

$count_values = Ubound($line)

```
If $count_values = 14 Then
 $new_line = $line[1] & "," & $line[2] & "," & $line[3] & "," & $line[4] & "," & $line[5] & "," & $line[6] & "," & $line[7] & "," & $line[8] & "," & $line[9] & "," & $line[10] & "," & $line[12] & "," & $line[13]
Else
 $new_line = $line
EndIf
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringSplit` has already a counter (element 0), so no need to use `Ubound`).

Like `StringSplit` converts a string to an array, `ArrayToString` converts an array back to a string.

```
#include <array.au3>
$tmp_line = "ABC,0,ABCD,ABC,ABC,ABC,ABC,ABC,11,ABC,ABC, ToRemove,012,234"
$line = StringSplit($tmp_line, ",")
If $line[0] = 14 Then
 $new_line = ArrayToString($line, ",", 1, 11) & "," & ArrayToString($line, ",", 13)
Else
 $new_line = $line  ; shouldn't this be $new_line = $tmp_line ?
EndIf
MsgBox(0, $line[0], $tmp_line & @CRLF & $new_line)
```